# Semaphore ctor failed in Windows 8 x64 when using "low integrity level"

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, windows-8, .net-4.5

I'm trying to create/open a named Semaphore in desktop application in Windows 8 x64  with low integrity level using .Net 4.0/4.5.

Same code works on Windows 7 x64 but fail on Windows 8 Entreprise x64 with a System.IO.IOException: "A required privilege is not held by the client".

Code is as follow (a console application):

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      System.Security.AccessControl.SemaphoreSecurity sec = null;

      //[low integrity level[
      sec = new System.Security.AccessControl.SemaphoreSecurity();
      sec.SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm("S:(ML;;NW;;;LW)");
      //]low integrity level]

      try
      {
         bool createdNew;
         var sem = new System.Threading.Semaphore(0, int.MaxValue, "MySemaphoreName", out createdNew, sec);
         if (createdNew) { Console.WriteLine("Semaphore created"); }
         else            { Console.WriteLine("Semaphore opened"); }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Exception occured {0}", ex);
      }
      ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey();
   }
}
```

It works on both system when removing following block:

```
sec = new System.Security.AccessControl.SemaphoreSecurity();
sec.SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm("S:(ML;;NW;;;LW)");
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: This question needs a lot more context.  There were significant changes in the Windows 8 security model with a new integrity level designed to provide the sandbox for Store apps.  The browser's protect mode model got changed too.  SDDL is deprecated.

Comment: @Hans Passant I'm aware of App Container but I prefer to keep my code not too OS version dependent.  Where have you seen that SDDL is deprecated on Windows 8? And why a System.IO.IOException: "A required privilege is not held by the client"?

Comment: Integrity level  doesn't seem to be deprecated for Desktop application. Desktop IE use it as explain [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Windows_8_Integration) and we can check it with Process Explorer.